# Where would I find Custom menu attributes in the database?

Tags: menus, database

In what table would I find the title of a custom menu in MySQL for Wordpress 3.5.x?

Answer (score 2):

Nav menu items are *posts* of the type `nav_menu_item`. They are combined to a nav menu by an assigned term from the taxonomy `nav_menu`. Each nav menu is a collection of posts under a term.

The function `wp_get_nav_menu_items()` is probably the best start to explore this.

1. The tables `{$prefix}_terms` and `{$prefix}_term_taxonomy` are queried for the current nav menu.
2. `{$prefix}_term_relationships` and `{$prefix}_term_taxonomy` are queried to find the posts assigned to that menu (term).
3. `{$prefix}_posts` is queried to get the posts.
4. `{$prefix}_postmeta` is queried to get the post meta data.

So the data for a nav menu are spread over four tables.

To see all the queries, add the following to your `wp-config.php`:

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG',         TRUE );
define( 'SAVEQUERIES',      TRUE );
```

The install and activate the [plugin Debug Bar](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/debug-bar/), go to a page with a menu and open the debug menu. There is a tab **Queries** with all the queries WordPress has done for that page.